How to effectively iterate through categories
I have a large dataframe -> lazyframe that was cut by the Expr.cut function. Now I would like to iterate through these categories, but I failed to find an effective way. When I use group_by, it tells me it is not iterable (unless I collect it before the grouping). It raises:

TypeError: 'LazyGroupBy' object is not iterable

I really don't want to filter the whole lazyframe for every category. How to achieve it?
The code I would love to be working (namely the for cycle in the end):
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

data = pl.LazyFrame(dict(
    a = np.linspace(1,5,100),
    b = np.linspace(20,30,100),
    ))


N_bins = 10
cutPoints = np.linspace(
    data.select(pl.max("a")).collect(),
    data.select(pl.min("a")).collect(),
    N_bins
    )

data = data.with_columns(
    pl.col("a").cut(cutPoints)
    )
groups = data.group_by("a")

for name, group in groups: 
    print( name)
    print(group)


Is there a particular reason you need to iterate through them at the "Python level"? Like, what will the next step in your task be? Perhaps it can be done at the "Polars level" instead.

It probably will (or maybe not, I not done with the project yet), but I need a feedback about the data I am working with. I would really like to see some portion of my data for debug purposes and of course if I step into something that is not possible using purely Polars, I would be very sad to do everything again.

If you want the data, you would need to call .collect() - no? I'm not sure how else it would work.

Yes, .collect() and .fetch() are examples of function I would like to use to individual dataframes in the group_by object. But how to acces an individual dataframe?

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding here, but why can't you .agg().collect()?

well, for some reason .agg() gave me errors before but now it works... Apparently the solution is groups.agg(pl.col("b")).fetch(). Thanks for claryfying :)

You were not so far off. Iterate over the rows of grouped_data using iter_rows(named=True). For each row you need to access the grouped values using the dictionary keys row['a_cut'], row['mean_a'], and row['mean_b']. THis is a version of your code that works:
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

data = pl.LazyFrame(dict(
    a = np.linspace(1, 5, 100),
    b = np.linspace(20, 30, 100),
))

N_bins = 10

cutPoints = np.linspace(
    data.select(pl.min("a")).collect().to_numpy()[0][0],
    data.select(pl.max("a")).collect().to_numpy()[0][0],
    N_bins + 1  
)

data = data.with_columns(
    pl.col("a").cut(cutPoints).alias("a_cut")
)

grouped_data = data.group_by("a_cut").agg([
    pl.col("a").mean().alias("mean_a"),
    pl.col("b").mean().alias("mean_b")
]).collect()

for row in grouped_data.iter_rows(named=True):
    print(f"Group: {row['a_cut']}")
    print(f"Mean a: {row['mean_a']}")
    print(f"Mean b: {row['mean_b']}\n")

which gives you
Group: (-inf, 1]
Mean a: 1.0
Mean b: 20.0

Group: (1, 1.4]
Mean a: 1.202020202020202
Mean b: 20.505050505050505

Group: (1.4, 1.8]
Mean a: 1.585858585858586
Mean b: 21.464646464646464

Group: (1.8, 2.2]
Mean a: 1.98989898989899
Mean b: 22.47474747474747

Group: (2.2, 2.6]
Mean a: 2.3939393939393936
Mean b: 23.48484848484848

Group: (2.6, 3]
Mean a: 2.797979797979798
Mean b: 24.49494949494949

Group: (3, 3.4000000000000004]
Mean a: 3.202020202020202
Mean b: 25.5050505050505

Group: (3.4000000000000004, 3.8000000000000003]
Mean a: 3.6060606060606064
Mean b: 26.515151515151512

Group: (3.8000000000000003, 4.2]
Mean a: 4.01010101010101
Mean b: 27.525252525252522

Group: (4.2, 4.6]
Mean a: 4.414141414141414
Mean b: 28.535353535353533

Group: (4.6, 5]
Mean a: 4.818181818181818
Mean b: 29.545454545454543

